# Does datastax opscenter community edition support multiple nodes?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have been banging my head against the wall for two days now, I can't get opscenter to add other nodes in the cluster, it only adds the localhost node (127.0.0.1) and when I try to add more it gives me `Error provisioning cluster: Request ID is invalid`. A friend told me maybe the community edition doesn't support multiple nodes.

I think it does, but I just want to keep debugging knowing that I'm going somewhere, instead of having the doubt it will never work.

If so, I will post another question with my complete settings.

#### Update

Here is the link of my question:
[datastax Opscenter can't add nodes, "Error provisioning cluster: Request ID is invalid" ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193091/datastax-opscenter-cant-add-nodes-error-provisioning-cluster-request-id-is-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, community edition supports multiple nodes and multiple DC's.

Go ahead and post and add the link here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have added the link.