# datastax Opscenter can't add nodes, "Error provisioning cluster: Request ID is invalid" ,

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

#### Update 2

There was a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241486/why-datastax-community-edition-installation-turned-out-to-be-enterprise/32268060) in Opscenter not matching dsc22 configuration with cassandra community version, this solved one problem.

#### Update

After reading the opscenter log again I think there actually something wrong with the 4 authentication fields or some ssh configuration, but I still don't know what exactly should be done, The field says "Local node credentials (sudo) private key (optional)

---

the scenario is as following:

1. I installed 4 nodes with vagrant and ansible where each has dsc22,opscenter (redundant I know),datastax-agent,cassandra-tool, oracle java 8
2. configuration below
3. nodetool status, everything is good they all see each other
4. I create a keyspace, it replicates to all the nodes just fine
5. on my host machine I open the datastax using the forwarded port from node02 for example.
6. First time I see two choices `add existing cluster` or `manage existing one` When I try to manage existing cluster > add 192.168.50.3 
   I get the following:
   [image]
7. So I try using 127.0.0.1, it works just fine but I only see this machine local cassandra node only.
8. So I try to add nodes from inside when I get a dialog (**I think this is important**) it has credentials fields i add admin,admin for repository, and also admin,admin for local username, I actually don't know what to put in these 4 fields, whether these are created or they're actually preconfigured somewhere else
9. So after I add some node to the data center with RAC info etc, I get the "Error provisioning cluster: Request ID is invalid" 
   [image]

I have no clue where the problem is, the only unknown step I did was the credentials thing (repository username/pass, local username/pass) when I add nodes from inside. But why I can't do the manage existing from the beginning where I only get in when I use 127.0.0.1 as ip.

So here's the datastax-agent:

```
Starting DataStax agent monitor datastax_agent_monitor.
 INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,506 Loading conf files: /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,657 Java vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_60
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,657 DataStax Agent version: 5.2.0
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,732 Default config values: {:cassandra_port 9042, :rollups300_ttl 2419200, :settings_cf "settings", :restore_req_update_period 60, :my_$
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,740 Waiting for the config from OpsCenter
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,752 Starting Stomp
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,752 Starting up agent communcation with OpsCenter.
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,753 Reconnecting to a backup OpsCenter instance
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,756 SSL communication is disabled
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,757 Creating stomp connection to 192.168.50.3:61620
  INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,756 Using 127.0.0.1 as the cassandra broadcast address
  INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,762 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,787 Reconnecting in 0s.
  INFO [main] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,791 Starting Jetty server: {:join? false, :ssl? false, :host nil, :port 61621}
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:39:59,872 Connected to 192.168.50.3:61620
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,200 Got new config from OpsCenter [note values in address.yaml override those from OpsCenter]: {:cassandra_port 904$
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,224 Starting up agent collection.
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,225 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [Jetty] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,347 Jetty server started
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,452 agent RPC address is  127.0.0.1
  INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,454 cassandra RPC address is  nil
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,471 Starting OS metric collectors (Linux)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,516 Starting Cassandra JMX metric collectors
  INFO [install-location-finder] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,614 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,639 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-08-24 22:40:00,793 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-0] 2015-08-24 22:40:02,094 Attempting to load stored metric values.
```

Here's full opscenter log http://pastebin.com/fXT2vkFR
The following is section from it:

```
 2015-08-24 23:13:38+0000 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2015-08-24 23:13:38+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Done loading persisted scheduled job descriptions
2015-08-24 23:13:40+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Using 192.168.50.4 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2015-08-24 23:13:40+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node <Node 127.0.0.1='-6574032654670847999'> changed version to {'search': None, 'jobtracker': None, 'tasktracker': None, 'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, 'dse': None, 'cassandra': u'2.2.0'}
2015-08-24 23:13:40+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Processing spark version {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}
2015-08-24 23:13:40+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node <Node 127.0.0.1='-6574032654670847999'> changed version to {u'search': None, u'jobtracker': None, u'tasktracker': None, u'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, u'dse': None, u'cassandra': u'2.2.0'}
2015-08-24 23:13:40+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Processing spark version {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}
2015-08-24 23:13:40+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node 127.0.0.1 changed its mode to normal
2015-08-24 23:13:40+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Done loading persisted alert rules
2015-08-24 23:13:41+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: OpsCenter starting up.
2015-08-24 23:13:42+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Using 192.168.50.2 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2015-08-24 23:13:42+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node <Node 127.0.0.1='-6574032654670847999'> changed version to {'search': None, 'jobtracker': None, 'tasktracker': None, 'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, 'dse': None, 'cassandra': u'2.2.0'}
2015-08-24 23:13:42+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Processing spark version {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}
2015-08-24 23:13:42+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node <Node 127.0.0.1='-6574032654670847999'> changed version to {u'search': None, u'jobtracker': None, u'tasktracker': None, u'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, u'dse': None, u'cassandra': u'2.2.0'}
2015-08-24 23:13:42+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Processing spark version {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}
2015-08-24 23:13:42+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node 127.0.0.1 changed its mode to normal
2015-08-24 23:13:42+0000 []  INFO: Starting to update agents' configuration
2015-08-24 23:13:47+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Using 192.168.50.5 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2015-08-24 23:13:48+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Using 192.168.50.4 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2015-08-24 23:13:49+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Using 192.168.50.3 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2015-08-24 23:13:49+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node <Node 127.0.0.1='-6574032654670847999'> changed version to {'search': None, 'jobtracker': None, 'tasktracker': None, 'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, 'dse': None, 'cassandra': u'2.2.0'}
2015-08-24 23:13:49+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Processing spark version {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}
2015-08-24 23:13:49+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node <Node 127.0.0.1='-6574032654670847999'> changed version to {u'search': None, u'jobtracker': None, u'tasktracker': None, u'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, u'dse': None, u'cassandra': u'2.2.0'}
2015-08-24 23:13:49+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Processing spark version {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}
2015-08-24 23:13:49+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node 127.0.0.1 changed its mode to normal
2015-08-24 23:13:58+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Using 192.168.50.3 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2015-08-24 23:13:58+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Using 192.168.50.2 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2015-08-24 23:14:22+0000 []  INFO: Testing SSH connectivity to 192.168.50.4
2015-08-24 23:14:23+0000 []  INFO: Testing SSH login to 192.168.50.4
2015-08-24 23:14:29+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:14:29+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:14:41+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:14:41+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:14:52+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:14:52+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:15:03+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:15:03+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:15:14+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:15:14+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:15:26+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:15:26+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:15:38+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:15:38+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:15:50+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:15:50+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:16:01+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed

2015-08-24 23:16:01+0000 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-08-24 23:16:13+0000 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 192.168.50.4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'192.168.50.4' failed
```

### Configuration

I'm using vagrant to create my vms with

```
... a section from the vagrantfile
config.vm.define "node02" do |node|
    node.vm.host_name = "node02"
    node.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8888, host: 3023
    node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.2", virtualbox__intnet: "intnet"
end
...
```

A section from the cassandra.yaml in each node

```
- seeds: "192.168.50.xx, 192.168.50.xx, ... rest of nodes"
```

The address.yaml in each node

```
# couple of nodes that have opscenter
# The following hosts line is commented out because when I use it the datastax-agent doesn't connect to any nodes, so I guess the default is 127.0.0.1 which works fine
# hosts: ["192.168.50.xx","192.168.50.xx"]

local_interface: 127.0.0.1

# opscenter ip
stomp_interface: 192.168.50.xx  
# this nodeXX ip
agent_rpc_broadcast_address: 192.168.50.xx
```

A section from cassandra-env.sh, note I don't use any authentication for jmx

```
LOCAL_JMX=NO

if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
else
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

---

nodetool status:

```
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.50.2  982.74 KB  256          ?       a35..  RAC1
UN  192.168.50.3  679.05 KB  256          ?       e6c..  RAC1
UN  192.168.50.4  912.1 KB   256          ?       634..  RAC1
UN  192.168.50.5  939.55 KB  256          ?       0a...  RAC1
```

Comment: Do you have SSL enabled client to node? That's one thing you have to provide when adding a cluster to Opscenter although usually the error is different to what you are getting.

Comment: no I don't have ssl enabled, I'm planning to do so anyway, but I originally thought If i can't get it to work without ssl, how would I do when ssl config complexity is added, but if you're saying that I **have to** in order to be able to connect to all nodes then can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I think there is some credentials thing not working but I don't know where, right now I'm thinking of enabling cassandra authentication in jmx in cassandra-env.sh then try these credentials in the 4 fields, and search more about the ssh error I get

Comment: You don't need SSL or client to node encryption to run OpsCenter

Comment: 1) Can you print the output of nodetool status? 2) Does your cassandra user have sudoer access 3) are you running OpsCenter, the agents, and the DSC process with the cassandra user?

Comment: @phact 1) yes, I've added output of it,  2) no I didn't add cassandra to sudo group, and I checked it's not sudoer,  3) no I'm running as a root

Comment: You should run DSC, OpsCenter, and the datastax-agent all with the Cassandra user. The Cassandra user should be in sudoers.

Comment: thanks phact for your help, I will change to cassandra user, but before that I noticed something really strange, the Package of opscenter says its enterprise not community edition here's the [question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241486/why-datastax-community-edition-installation-turned-out-to-be-enterprise)