# Why Datastax community edition installation turned out to be enterprise?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

#### Update

Ok, some more factors discovered, this image was taken after I clicked using "manage existing cluster, and added 127.0.0.1 as host node" so I guess there should be a configuration where I can set the package to be community edition not enterprise.

But If I do create new cluster where I'm able to pick community edition package, the problem is that it tries to install cassandra and datastax-agent over these nodes and finishes with errors dismiss and retry

---

While trying to fix a [cassandra configuration problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193091/datastax-opscenter-cant-add-nodes-error-provisioning-cluster-request-id-is-i) I noticed two things in my installation:

1. The datastax enterprise credentials text fields ? which lead me to 2
2. That the installed `Package: Datastax Enterprise 4.7.0` while I actually installed cassandra and opscenter from Deb community using ansible

Here is the part in ansible config, where the repo link is community:

```
- name: Add Datastax repository key
  apt_key: url=http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key state=present
  tags:
    - install

- name: Add Datastax repository
  apt_repository: repo='deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main' state=present update_cache=yes
  tags:
    - install

- name: Install Cassandra
  apt: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - dsc22
    - cassandra-tools
    - opscenter
  tags:
    - install
```

[image]

Comment: Let me guess, you're running Cassandra 2.2? The latest OpsCenter doesn't include the definitions for this version of Cassandra, and therefore it grays out this screen. Happened to me last week as well, and I had to add the definitions myself to get it to work. I guess we'll have to wait for DataStax to update OpsCenter.

Comment: @uri2x where did you put the definitions ? can you please supply it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest OpsCenter doesn't include the definitions for the latest version of Cassandra Community, and therefore it grays out this screen. Here's how I solved it:

At /etc/opscenter/definitions/ :

1. Copy `dsc-packages-2.1.0.json` to `dsc-packages-2.3.0.json`
2. Edit `packages-1.json`, `packages-5.1.2.json`, and `packages-5.2.0.json` and duplicated every 2.1.4 line with a 2.2.0 line.

Comment: Thanks, for any comming readers I've followed the instructions but changed the values to fit the version that I have